# Short url mecanism : base36

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework-2.2

In my postgreSQL database, I have a `bigint` and it's `base36` conversion.

I have urls containing short_id in `base36` and the decimal version, but I will query according to the url so base36.

Can `base36` short_id be my `primary key` for better performance ?

Comment: Test it. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html (hint: primary keys will use btree indexes)

Answer (score 1):

At least in PostgreSQL, the `PRIMARY KEY` isn't about performance. It's about correctness and data structure. The query planner doesn't care about the `PRIMARY KEY`, only about the `UNIQUE NOT NULL` index that's created by defining the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

You can define whatever indexes you like. Want another unique index? Just create one.

If the `base36` column is guaranteed unique then yes, it is a candidate for a primary key. Whether it's the best choice, and whether it's actually any faster than whatever you're currently doing, is somewhat app dependent.

Note that extra indexes aren't free - they do incur a cost for inserts and updates. So don't go crazy creating multiple indexes on every column for write-heavy tables.

---

BTW, some other database systems *do* have stronger performance implications for the `PRIMARY KEY`. In particular, on DB systems that use index-organized tables (where the main table is in a b-tree structure) the choice of the clustering key - usually also the primary key - is a big thing for performance.

In PostgreSQL every table is just a heap, so it's not relevant.